# How to query string to a web site using get method?

Tags: c#, httprequest, getmethod

I want to send an information along with the url like a query string to the web site. This is exactly I call

```
Process.Start("http://domain.com?value=anything");
```

but I don't want to open browser because don't want to interrupt the user who is using the software.

I have googled for this but I found some `HttpRequest` code but the problem is this those program is not appending the query string. They are just returning me the html text of the web page.

I want to retrieve that information to store in database. Please guide me in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is something I use to perform a GET:

```
public T Get<T>(string url, IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, string>> data)
{
    var webApiUri = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["WebApiUri"];

    var client = new HttpClient();

    try
    {
        string queryString = string.Empty;

        if (data != null)
        {
            queryString = data.Distinct().Select(x => string.Format("{0}={1}", x.Key, x.Value)).ToDelimitedString("&");
        }

        var response = client.GetAsync(string.Format("{0}/{1}?{2}", webApiUri, url, queryString)).Result;
        var responseContent = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
        return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(responseContent);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Debug.Assert(false, ex.Message);
        throw;
    }
}
```

`T` is the return type of the method. The response is expected as JSON, but you don't have to worry about that part. It's how the `client` performs a GET request that you're interested in. This is just example based around a JSON result.

Comment: See edits. Its just an example of how to perform a GET request to website with some information. I'm trying to help the OP and this is what I understand him to be asking.

Answer (score 4):

Use [`WebClient.DownloadString`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fhd1f0sw(v=vs.110).aspx) to get a page from a specific url, without using browsers:

```
var x = WebClient.DownloadString("http://domain.com?value=anything");
```

Comment: My problem is something differ. I want to append my querystring in web url so on my web application that information can be retrived.

Comment: in ur comment that snippet is retrieving information. But I want to append my information in querystring. so on web site I can store that information in database.

Comment: So your question is: how to create a query string?

Comment: Yes. Can you assist me in this case?

Comment: Query strings are only parameters (although you can supply them with a POST). I never read he wants a POST.

Comment: So, this sends information, right? I think OP should clarify.

Comment: The use of `HttpClient` is overkill here. `DownloadString` does a GET too.

Comment: @user3756000: I would be glad to help but you need to explain yourself better.

Comment: My clarification about the problem is this I want to use web service kind of facility where I can provide the web developer some information from my desktop application via query string but in hidden form. As I have mentioned in my above given problem that I want to transfer information in hidden form.